# Certain CSS properties not being applied inside an iframe

Tags: html, css, iframe

First of all, let me preface this by saying I am NOT trying to apply additional CSS to the contents of an iframe from the parent document. I am having issues with a perfectly working document that when displayed in an iframe, the styling breaks. I only say this because whenever I google this issue that's all I get.

I have an HTML document that works and displays perfectly fine when viewed in a browser by itself, however I need to show this content in an iframe. The issue is that somehow, it seems like it's randomly picking and choosing which CSS properties get applied.

For example, if you check the fiddle linked below and inspect one of the list items in the iframe, you can see that the `li` tags have a `border-bottom` set. However, if you look at the `.service ul li` selector in the code, you'll see that there is actually a `border-left` and `border-right` there as well which are being ignored. This is only one of the many weird things happening. If you inspect around the document you'll see more instances where this happens.

I've never seen anything like this and it makes no sense at all. I can literally see elements in the inspector where some CSS properties from the same selector are working, and some are ignored. This document displays without issue outside of an iframe.

[fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/n790o4Lp/)

BTW the code is loaded from a data string rather than a URL because it's rendered from an ejs template and it is not served on a public route, nor do I want it to be. However this should be irrelevant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a conflict with the hash "#" symbol in your css. Switching your hex color to red fixes the issue in your fiddle. You will have to come up with another way to add the color without introducing unwanted characters inside your iframe html code that is inside an attribute.